# p:datatable f:facet name="output" does not display

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

Some basic information:
- Primefaces Version: **5.3**
- Primefaces Extension Version: **3.1.0**
- Java Server Faces: **2.0**

---

I try to display a editable table but somehow the rows aren't displayed properly - you don't see any value but if you click the text input field appears with the right value which is weird...
[image: Here you can see that if nothing is selected the value wont display] [image: Here you can see that the value appears after one clicks the field]

#### The xhtml file

I deleted some things from the source (replaced with -)

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/views/templates/userTemplate.xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

  <ui:define name="content">

    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="oe" rowKey="#{oe.id}" value="#{showSomethingMgdBean.allUser}" lazy="true" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">

      <p:column headerText="id" style="text-align: center;">
        <p:cellEditor>
          <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{oe.id}" />
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{oe.id}" style="width:96%" />
          </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="-">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.-}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="-">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.-}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="-">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.-}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="-">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.-}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="enabled">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.enabled}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="expired">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.expired}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="locked">
        <h:outputText value="#{oe.locked}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
        <p:rowEditor />
      </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

If you need more informations let me know. Maybe it's because of my the xhtml / jsf declaration at the beginning of the file?

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/views/templates/userTemplate.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
```

Comment: look at the html source in the browser, try without a template, without any custom css etc... or in other words, try to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I had the css and javascript files of prime-ui integrated aswell as the primefaces things in tomcat so i guess the prime-ui files had the other files overwritten and therefor i couldnt use some features of primefaces or atleast it was messing with the css. So i deleted all custom css things like @Kukeltje mentioned in the comments and it worked! :D

Comment: The power of a [mcve]! Remember this for future issues!